# Cross-Domain request when server does NOT support JSONP

Tags: jquery, json, get, cross-domain, jsonp

Im trying to solve this problem for hours now.
I got a [wikia web](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com) which I want to get stuff from but it supports only json, not even xml or jsonp.

I tried everything. If I call it as jsonp my client returns error "SyntaxError: invalid label" cause the server doesnt return it as jsonp or json at all.
If I add "callback=?" to the url and leave it as json, same error returned.

Here is part of my code (I modified it too many times and nothing worked so far)

```
$('#searchBox').keydown(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/index.php?callback=?",
        data: {
            action: "ajax",
            rs: "getLinkSuggest",
            format: "json",
            query: "jungl"
        },
        success: function(json){
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**
Here is my solution, which works:
(Using YQL)

```
    var url = "http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/index.php?action=ajax&rs=getLinkSuggest&format=json&query=jung"
    url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + url + '"') + '&format=xml';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(text){
            text = text.split("<p>")[1].split("</p>")[0];
            alert(text);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        },
        dataType: "text"
});
```

Comment: Cross domain ajax call is not supported. You can use some server side technology to grab the json data from the external site and then use it in jquery.

Answer (score 2):

If the remote server doesn't support JSONP or allow CORS, then you'll have to bounce the request server-side to bypass the same-origin rule.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do crossdomain AJAX without JSONP or CORS.

Nevertheless you can code an HTTP proxy in backend to do request in backend instead of the user (= js).

Comment: Is it possible to just download the entire page (with all of the html tags) and then regex the stuff I need into a json string ?
I cant use php at all cause this js code will run in Chrome Plugin, so no php.