# cross-domain data with AJAX using JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to get data from Geobytes. One of the templates returns JSON and I need to cross-domain access it.

I wrote these 2 functions

```
function getCountry(ip) {
    var surl = "http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=json.txt";
    $.ajax({
        url: surl,
        data: '{"ipaddress":"' + ip + '"}',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        processData: false,
        jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

function jsonpcallback(rtndata) {
    alert(rtndata.message);
}
```

The call is executed successfully, these are my response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 17 Nov 2012 12:43:54 GMT
Expires: 0
Content-type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

the returned data is JSON, but I get

> warning: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=json.txt&callback=jsonpcallback&{%22ipaddress%22:%22200.167.254.166%22}&_=1353148931121"
>
> Error on the remote IpLocator.htm: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

The error is thrown on the returned data at

```
{"geobytes":{"countryid":117,
```

I think is maybe because it's 117 and not "117" but I obviously can't control the returned data. Tried to add a "processData=false" but that didn't help.

I've added the error handling to the ajax and get "parsererror" on the status

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you skip ajax call and just try to call $.parseJSON on  the fixed string? In other words, copy the result, fix the "117" issue and see if that gets around the parse error. That will tell you if that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to [no.andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993100/no-andrea/) for pointing me to the right direction!

As I'm using MVC3 I've added a new controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JsonGetCountry(string ip)
{
    try
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation");
        sb.Append("&template=json.txt");
        sb.Append("&IpAddress=");
        sb.Append(ip);

        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var data = webClient.OpenRead(sb.ToString());

        if (data == null) { return Json(""); }

        var reader = new StreamReader(data);
        var msg = reader.ReadToEnd();
        data.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return Json(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

and updated my JQuery function to

```
function getCountry(ip) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/My-Shop/IP/JsonGetCountry",
        data: '{"ip":"' + ip + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var a = $.parseJSON(msg);
            alert(a.geobytes.iso2);
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert(ex.statusText);
    }
});
```

And that fixed all my problems :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify the field dataType like this:

```
...
dataType: "jsonp json",
...
```

In this way the data yo get will be parsed as json.

Following the documentation:

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try >to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.

In your case the MIME you get is text/html, adding the "json" value to the dataType, you tell jQuery to treat the response as json and not text.

If the service do not support JSONP you can make your own proxy page to handle the request, or using YQL as described here: [Cross-Domain request when server does NOT support JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195063/cross-domain-request-when-server-does-not-support-jsonp)

Comment: @kooshka are you sure that this service supports jsonp? I ran the code and does not seem so.

Comment: No it doesn't support it but that isn't a show stopper. if you enter "http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=json.txt&IpAddress=200.167.254.165" on your browser you get json back, and I get it with my ajax function. the problem is the parser error

Comment: yes, it works on the browser with the direct url because you have not to deal with the same origin policy. but your jsonpcallback function is never called, as you can see if you add "alert(error.message)" in your error function. so actually you cannot get the data. You have to make a proxy page on your domain to do the call.